# Issue adding transition effect on div for show hide functionality

Tags: css

I have a show/hide on a div block which is working fine. I'm just having an issue adding the transition animation effect to make it open and close smoother and it doesn't seem to be applying for me. Any help would be great, code below:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("one");

function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("but");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.innerHTML = "Close";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.innerHTML = "Open";
  }
}

var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  x.classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
#one {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear;
}

#one.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  This is an element.
</div>

<button id="but" onclick="myFunction()">Close</button>
```

Comment: To make a `transition` on the `opacity` you need to animate the `opacity` instead of `display`.  `x.style.opacity = y.innerHTML=== "Close" ? 0 : 1`

Answer (score 0):

You have written CSS to animate opacity but you are never dealing with it in your JavaScript. `display` property cannot be animated just yet, it is upcoming feature in CSS.

You have a nice CSS declaration of `#one.hide`, where you set the `opacity: 0`. Use JavaScript to check if the 'hide' class is there or not in your element using `element.classList` interface. If there is a 'hide' class it means the element is hidden, you should remove it from there so that it opens and change the button's text to 'close'. Do the exact opposite if there is no 'hide' class (the element is open).

Also set `visibility: hidden` in `#one.hide` so that it becomes unelectable. And also add `visibility 0.5s linear` in the transition property or simply `all 0.5s linear` so that animation also happens when closing (otherwise it will only animate when showing not when hiding).

```js
var x = document.getElementById("one");

function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("but");

  if (x.classList.contains("hide")) {
    x.classList.add("hide");
    y.innerHTML = "close";
  } else {
    x.classList.remove("hide");
    y.innerHTML = "open"
  }
}

var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  x.classList.toggle('hide');
});
```

```css
#one {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear, visibility 0.5s linear; // or just -> all 0.5s linear
}

#one.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  This is an element.
</div>

<button id="but" onclick="myFunction()">Close</button>
```